# Inf results of LOF(Package dbscan) in R

Tags: r

In my research I detect timeseries outliers with the several methods. One of them is **local outlier factor** (**LOF**). For this purpose I use **lof** method from **dbscan** package in **R** language. [Description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/dbscan.pdf) says that:

> if there are more than **k** duplicate points in the data, then
>   **lof** can become NaN caused by an infinite local density. In this case we set lof to 1.

But I didn't see 1 lof, only Inf values for such case (more than **k** duplicate points in the data). In addition, I've got Inf value for gross outliers (for example, I have 0 value in timeserie of atmospheric pressure) while **k** < 4.

Code example:

```
library("fpc")
#Simulation of atmospheric pressure
for (i in 1:700) {
  P__[i]<-1024
  if (i%%4 == 0) {
    rn<-runif(1, 0.5, 10.5)
    P__[i]<-P__[i] + rn
  }
}
#Simulated outlier
P__[150]<-0

P__<-as.matrix(P__)

lof_local<-as.matrix(dbscan::lof(x = P__,k = 4))
print (lof_local[150]) #Inf
print (lof_local[108]) #1.04278

lof_local<-as.matrix(dbscan::lof(x = P__,k = 10))
print (lof_local[150]) #Inf
print (lof_local[108]) #1.167718

lof_local<-as.matrix(dbscan::lof(x = P__,k = 20))
print (lof_local[150]) #Inf
print (lof_local[108]) #1.009134

lof_local<-as.matrix(dbscan::lof(x = P__,k = 50))
print (lof_local[150]) #Inf
print (lof_local[108]) #Inf. So, we have more than two Inf values
```

Can you explain me, why it arose?

Comment: Need an example and code to create the situation you are discussing. Also need you to improve the description of your problem or the result you would like. At the moment: ` Can you help me, why it happens?` is not particularly informative about "how" to help.

Comment: 42-, I edited my post.

Comment: I find that we get Inf result when there are several equal values in neighboring k-set of checking timeserie value. I suppose that it arose because of dividing by zero. But I would like to find an outlier, and Inf may arise while it occurs in studying timeserie. Very often there are many equal **non-outlier** values in studying timeserie. So we can exclude these duplicate points, but in this case if we are studying **lof**, we have no clear criterion to achieve a goal - to obtain optimus **k** value.

Comment: So, I will be very pleased if anybody say me alternate solutions of how to detect an outlier in real timeserie with the several duplicate points using **lof** method in view of the foregoing. At the moment I can detect virtually all outliers, but can lost an outlier between the sequence of  the timeserie duplicate  points.